# C# - Importing Excel file without knowing the sheet name

Tags: c#, oledb, import-from-excel, oledbcommand

I'm trying to import an Excel file and my logic to do that is correct :

```
private void SaveFileToDB(UploadedFile uploadedFile)
{
        string path = Server.MapPath("uploads/" + uploadedFile.FileName);


        int currentContractId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);

        string connnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connnection);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(**"select * from [Sheet1$]"**, con);

        myCommand.Fill(dt);
        int count = 0;
        //some code...

}
```

As you can see, I'm hardcoding the name of the Excel Sheet in my command and I wanted to know how to proceed to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to avoid using Interop and want to just use oledb, you can use the below to get the sheet names:

```
var sheetNames = con.GetSchema("Tables");
foreach (DataRow row in sheetNames.Rows)
{
   var name = row["TABLE_NAME"];
   //select from this sheet
   //do whatever else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is just to find all sheets.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Book1.xlsx"); 

String[] excelSheets = new String[excelBook.Worksheets.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelBook.Worksheets)    
    {
      excelSheets[i] = wSheet.Name;
      i++;
    }
```

Source: [Excel Sheet Names in Sheet Order](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f459200-deef-4131-be8a-1b67a41efb97/excel-sheet-names-in-sheet-order?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)